# How to uninstall font-awesome gem and remove font asset from Rails 4.2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, font-awesome, assets

Help, I can't remove Font Awesome! I'm using font awesome in my Rails project, but due to high size and impact to page speed I want to completely remove it. 
I uninstalled font-awesome-rails gem and removed from Gemfile:

```
gem uninstall font-awesome-rails
```

Also, in application.scss I removed line:

```
*= require font-awesome
```

After all this Font Awesome is still there somehow. When I start server in dev mode and when I inspect I can see that browser is pulling again font-awesome.min.css and fontawesome-webfont from assets path. I cleared browser but it's still there. What else I can do?

**UPDATE 1:**

I added new version of Font Awesome Rails gem 4.7.0 to see what happens. Inspection via Chrome:

FA 4.7.0

```
http://****.io/assets/font-awesome.self-2a86d2017f4b74f22943750b3b50b9cb753581bab96cbdaaf2df53f4c04c995b.css?body=1
```

FA 4.1.0

```
http://****.io/assets/font-awesome.min.self-54ae95014c4e9e7f668af4d1b753a00a6ac5ed3376588d0409672682c7d62c5a.css?body=1
```

FA 4.1.0 - referred from 4.1.0 min css

```
http://****.io/assets/fonts/fontawesome-webfont-66db52b456efe7e29cec11fa09421d03cb09e37ed1b567307ec0444fd605ce31.woff?v=4.1.0
```

Comment: Did you bundle your project after you removed the gem from your Gemfile?

Comment: By "bundle your project" you mean what? I tried bundle, bundle install and bundle clean --force. After that a few server restarts. Nothing happens and Font Awesome is still here.

Comment: Also to mention, font-awesome is not included in any of my assets as standalone file. Added just as a gem.

Comment: Try to check out and run the project again. Do you use RVM? Use different RVM Gemset and try again. Without 'font-awesome-rails' gem in the Gemfile of course.

Comment: I checked out to previous commit. Again installed Font Awesome. I noticed that after gem bundle install, and putting line *= require font-awesome, it generates one more css file, font-awesome.css. File font-awesome.min.css is there too. Weird. Now I have 2 font-awesome css loaded.

Comment: Also, I'm using FontAwesome 4.7.0, the main file is same version when I include it in tree. I inspected with chrome tools, the MIN version that I can't remove is 4.1.0 ver.

Comment: It is possible, that once the font-awesome.css is compiled, it is not removed when the gem in uninstalled. Do you use git versioning? You could see it there, which files are added to the project.

Comment: I would recommend to check out the project in a new folder. Not just check out the commit.

Comment: This files are not in my git. Also, it will be tricky to make new folder and add project because I'm using C9 cloud based dev env. How to manually locate and delete this files?

Comment: Then what is the problem? If the files are not part of your git? Delete the project and check out the project again and the files won't be there. As far as I understood, you have added the gem and you did not know how to delete font's files. So my advice is, delete the project and check out the project again. The files should not be there, right?

Comment: I pulled project from my bitbucket to other IDE (Codenvy) on fresh mashine.  That weird font-awesome.min.css again appeared! Also, I updated code, please check it.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand it correctly. Did you have a problem to uninstall it? Maybe the uninstall of the gem is broken. But just simply revert the commit when you add gem FA gem, remove it from your repository and NEVER install it. If you check out this fixed version of the project again and you use new rvm gemset, it should not be there, as it cannot be installed. Make sure, that also you clear the compiled assets frist and you push this clean version to git before deploying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in gem **awesome-share-buttons**, which I used in my application to make posts sharable. Somehow when you install that gem it pulls Font Awesome 4.1.0, whole css and font package (over 100kb), probably to render social icons.

```
gem 'awesome-share-buttons'
```

I uninstalled gem **awesome-share-buttons** and all Font Awesome content has gone, just like I wanted.